# Dollar and Pound Issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I am developing a retail site which sends out a confirmation mail when a customer places and order. Currently the module i use has a XSL format to send the email and the prices in this are in $. Since this site will be used in the UK i want the $ symbol to be replaced by £

A part of my email is as follows

```
[[xsl:value-of select="format-number(price * /in/salesOrder/exchangeRate, '$#,##0.00')"/]]
```

This gives an output of $80.00 when show to the customer...

I changed this to

```
[[xsl:value-of select="format-number(price * /in/salesOrder/exchangeRate, '£#,##0.00')"/]]
```

However the email is shown in XSL format and give the customer the following

> [[xsl:value-of select="format-number(price *
>   /in/salesOrder/exchangeRate, '£#,##0.00')"/]]

How can i Fix this

Comment: are those really `[[` and `]]` instead of `<` and `>` respectively?

Comment: You tagged this XSLT, but the code you show is not exactly that. In XSLT, there should be no problem using `<xsl:value-of select="format-number($yourvalue, '£#,#00.00')"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
[[xsl:value-of select="concat('£', format-number(price * /in/salesOrder/exchangeRate, '#,##0.00'))"/]]
```